# Outlook 2007 Task Saving Problems

Tags: vba, outlook, save

I'm very new with VBA in Outlook.

So I'm trying to *manipulate the Save Button* for the Task Formulars.

I was wondering how to make a "different" Save Button wich actually does the same but with some extras.

So does anybody knows how you can save a Task that you're actually at with a VBA makro???

Thanks for Help

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new ribbon item that will be your custom button, this item should have your custom save function defined as its handler. Here is an example of how to customise the ribbon

```
namespace OutlookAddIn
{
[ComVisible(true)]
public class RibbonHook : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

    public RibbonHook()
    {
    }       

    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        string xml = string.Empty;

        switch (ribbonID)
        {
           case "Microsoft.Outlook.Task":
                xml = GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.RibbonTask.xml");
               break;               
        }

        return xml;           
    }



    #region Ribbon Callbacks
    //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, select the Ribbon XML item in Solution Explorer and then press F1

    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    }

    public void buttonTaskCustomSave_Action(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Outlook.Taskitem taskItem = (Outlook.taskItem)OutlookAddIn.Globals.OLA.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
       //do stuff with the task here
    }        

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                {
                    if (resourceReader != null)
                    {
                        return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

you will need to add this to your main addin class

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new RibbonHook();
    }
```

and this is the ribbon xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabTask">
    <group id="TaskCustom"
           label="Custom Save">
      <button id="buttonTaskCustomSave" label="Custom Save" onAction ="buttonTaskCustomSave_Action"/>         
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```